# UNIQUE results sorted and grouped to multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets

Need your help with this.
I have the followuing data in google sheets

[Google Sheets Sample file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eckLNysMwFgccFFWuJhk6EayaHHMIviqwgmaAs1EpNc/edit#gid=2100307022)

| Number | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Albert Stein |
| 1 | John Don |
| 2 | Jim Carter |
| 2 | John Don |
| 2 | Steve Mckeen |
| 1 | Mark Knoffler |
| 1 | Hellen Hunt |
| 4 | Mary Popins |
| 3 | Stewart Rod |
| 4 | Peter Pan |
| 3 | Christian |
| 3 | Bob Dylan |

With this query:

=transpose(query(unique(A:B);"select Col1,Col2 where Col1 is not null order by Col1"))

I get :

| Number | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name | Albert Stein | John Mcnamara | Mark Knoffler | Hellen Hunt | Jim Carter | John Don | Steve Mckeen | ... |

Your help will be much appreciated in order to obtain this result :

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Albert Stein | Jim Carter | Bob Dylan | Mary Popins |
| Hellen Hunt | John Don | Christian | Peter Pan |
| John Don | Steve Mckeen | Stewart Rod |  |
| Mark Knoffler |  |  |  |

I've been struggling with no success !
Thankx!!!!

Answer (score 1):

### Solution:

In D18 I entered

```
=transpose(arrayformula(iferror({sort(unique(A2:A)), split(regexreplace(trim(transpose(query(if((transpose(sort(unique(A2:A)))=sort(A2:A))*len(sort(A2:A)),sort(B2:B, A2:A, 1, 1, 1)&",",),,50000))),",$", ), ", ", 0)})))
```

### References:

- [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en)
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)
- [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en)
- [SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en)
- [UNIQUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en)
- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en)
- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en)
- [TRIM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140?hl=en&ref_topic=3105625)
- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)
- [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en&ref_topic=9054531)
- [LEN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you very very much!!! Your formula did the job!

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked, @PaulBoggs. Since you are new here, you may want to check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Cheers !